# A question about the range of a positive measure

Tags: measure-theory

It is a well-known fact that the range of a positive measure $\mu$ on a measure space $(X,\cal M)$ is the interval $[0,\mu(X)]$ provided $\mu$ is atomless (i.e., there is no measurable set $A\in \cal M$ such that $\mu(A)>0$ and for any measurable set $B\subset A$ we have $\mu(B)=0$ or $\mu(B)=\mu(A)$).

It seems that the 'standard' proof of this fact involves some transfinite induction argument (cf. e.g. Halmos 1947, Wikipedia or else), but I am looking for a proof not using transfinite induction as suggested by some exercises in Bourbaki or Dieudonné Analysis II.

This would entail proving the following:

Let $r\in ]0,\mu(X)[$, and let $\cal C=\{A\in \cal M:\mu(A)\le r\}$. Suppose that $\mu$ has a 'gap' at $r$, meaning that we have $\alpha<r$, where $\alpha=\sup\{\mu(A):A\in \cal C\}$. Then $\mu$ must have an atom.

A simple path leading to that result would be to prove that in the presence of a gap at $r$, $\cal C$ is closed under finite union; in other words, if $A,B$ are such that $\mu(A)\le \alpha$ and $\mu(B)\le \alpha$, then $A$ and $B$ have no other choice but to overlap in such a way that $\mu(A\cup B)\le \alpha$. Equivalently if $A$ and $B$ are supposed also disjoint, we must have $\mu(B)\le \alpha-\mu(A)$.

The intuitive argument is that if neither $A$ nor $B$ contains an atom, then $A\cup B$ cannot contain it. I would suspect the proof to be well-known, but my brain seems unable to produce it.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom%5F%28measure%5Ftheory%29#Non-atomic_measures

Comment: Thank you Christian for your answers. However, neither the wiki article nor the previous post on this site fullfill what I'm looking for. The proof proposed by wiki uses transfinite induction (Haussdorf's maximality theorem). For the other post on this site, it refers to an older proof due to Sierpinski that is constructive (and quite elegant, one of the first proofs of this kind I guess) but rather lengthy and works in R^n (allowing one to cut the measure space conveniently using regular grids).

Comment: Also, it is true that the general case can be reduced to a large extent to the case of Lebesgue measure on an interval, but I would like to know if a more direct argument not using transfinite induction works in the abstract case.

Comment: What you sketched doesn't seem to prove what you want: if the range of $\mu$ were a dense proper subset of $[0,\mu(X)]$, it would satisfy $\sup \{ \mu(A): A\in \mathcal{C}\} = r$.

Comment: But your "simple path" can't possibly work. Consider the set $\{a, b, c, d\}$ with the counting measure. Start with $r = 3/2$. Your set $\mathcal{C} = \{\{a\}, \{b\}, \{c\}, \{d\}\}$ and is not closed under finite union.

Comment: Remember that I am considering the case where $\mu$ is atomless (or at least is not purely atomic). In that case once we know that $\sup\{\mu(A):A\in\cal C\}=r$, the proof that there is a set $A\in \cal M$ such that $\mu(A)=r$ is straightforward (see below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) Existence of sets of small measure.

Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ an atomless finite measure space with $\mu(\Omega)>0$.
It is easy to show that any measurable set $A$ with $\mu(A)>0$ contains a measurable subset $B\subset A$ with $0<\mu(B)\le \mu(A)/2$, and therefore a measurable set $M$ of measure $0<\mu(M)\le \varepsilon$.

(2) The space and any measurable set is a numerable union of set of small measure.

Now given $\varepsilon>0$ consider the set $\mathcal M$ of measurable sets $M=\bigcup_n A_n$
union of a numerable set of measurable sets of measure $\mu(A_n)\le \varepsilon$

Let $\lambda$ the supremum of the measures $\mu(M)$ of set in $\mathcal M$.
There is a sequence $(M_n)$ of sets in $\mathcal M$ with $\lim_n\mu(M_n)=\lambda$. Then $M_0:=\bigcup M_n\in \mathcal M$ (by definition) and $\lambda(M_0)=\lambda$. But it follows that $\lambda=\mu(\Omega)$, because in other case $\Omega\smallsetminus M_0$ will contain a set of measure $\le \varepsilon$, which contradict the maximality of $M_0$.

(3) Given a measurable set $M$ and two numbers $0<a<b<\mu(M)$, there exists a measurable set $A\subset M$ with $a<\mu(A)<b$.

Let $\varepsilon=(b-a)/2$, by (2) the set $M$ can be put as a union of measurable sets of measure less than $\varepsilon$,  $M=\bigcup_n M_n$ with $\mu(M_n)\le \varepsilon$.  Then $$\lim_N\mu\Bigl(\bigcup_{n=1}^N M_n\Bigr)=\mu(M).$$ Therefore there is some $N$ such that $a<\mu\Bigl(\bigcup_{n=1}^N M_n\Bigr)<b$, since each $M_n$ have measure $\le (b-a)/2$.

(4) Construct the set with measure $\mu(A)=a$ for a given $0<a<\mu(\Omega)$.

We will construct a sequence of measurable sets $(A_n)$ with $A_n\le A_{n+1}$ and such that
$$\frac{a+\mu(A_n)}{2}<\mu(A_{n+1})< a.$$
It is clear that in this case $A=\bigcup_n A_n$ have measure $a$.

Start with $A_0=\emptyset$. We must construct $A_1$ with $a/2<\mu(A_1)<a$. Sincer $\Omega$ have measure $>a$, we have constructed such a set in (3).

Assume we have constructed $A_n$, then $\mu(A_n)<a$, applying (3) we construct $B_n\subset \Omega\smallsetminus A_n$ whose measure is greater than half the difference with our objective:  $a-\mu(A_n)>\mu(B_n)>\frac{a-\mu(A_n)}{2}$.
Hence  $A_{n+1}=A_n\cup B_n$ satisfies our requirement. First $A_n$ and $B_n$ are disjoint $\mu(A_{n+1})=\mu(A_n)+\mu(B_n)<a$, and $\mu(A_n)+\mu(B_n)>\frac{a+\mu(A_n)}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you Juan, this what I was looking for. That $X$ must be a denumerable union of sets of measure $\le \epsilon$ was the point I was missing.

Comment: @jacobul  I have ready a modification of my answer to make it more explicit when I see your suggestions. Now I am retired but I used this construction for years in my course of measure theory, suggested by other professor of my University.

Answer (score 0):

As note 'added in proof': the above answers in the positive the point I was trying to make, i.e. that in the presence of a gap at some $r>0$, the measure $\mu$ cannot be atomless.

Indeed, suppose that $\mu$ has a gap at $r$. Let $\alpha=\sup\{\mu(A):A\in \cal C\}$ and $\beta=\inf\{\mu(A):A\in \cal M, \mu(A)\ge r\}$. If $\mu$ were atomless, we know that for any $\epsilon>0$, we could write $X=\cup_{n\ge 1}A_n$ where the $A_n$'s are measurable sets of measure $\le \epsilon$. Hence for some $N\ge 1$ we would have $\alpha< \mu(\cup_{n=1}^{N} A_n)\le \alpha+\epsilon$, and taking $\epsilon<\beta-\alpha$ would yield a contradiction. Hence $\mu$ must have an atom.